Anaconda3 - downgrade python version to 3.11.8 in the current (base) environment
Windows 11 OS
I installed a clean Anaconda3 platform just 3 days ago. It came with Python 3.12.4. But it seems some things (PySpark related) just don't work with python 3.12.4.
For example, I am getting a similar error like this one here, when I try running some PySpark examples.
Error from PySpark code to showdataFrame : py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (laptop001 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)

So now I want to downgrade the python version in my Anaconda3 base env to 3.11.8.
Is it possible to downgrade the existing python version to 3.11.8 in the current (base) environment? If so, how?
I don't want to create a new conda environment (with 3.11.8) as most of the tutorials suggest. I just want to set python 3.11.8 in the current base environment. I am not finding any info anywhere if this can be done.

I think you might just have to reinstall Anaconda with the previous version (2024.02-1), which shipped with Python 3.11. You can find the installer packages for all versions at https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/.

@MattPitkin I thought about that too, but the Anaconda installation is heavy, takes a lot of time and disk space, and I also have limited Windows permissions on this laptop. So I want to avoid taking that route if possible.

Do you need the full Anaconda package, or would miniconda work for your needs https://docs.anaconda.com/miniconda/? If all you really need anaconda for is to create virtual environments via the command line (and you don't need/use bloat like Anaconda Navigator) then miniconda is a great option (and all I ever use).

Or even miniforge https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge.

@MattPitkin I think I will reinstall the full Anaconda3. Are you sure 2024.02-1 goes with Python 3.11 ?

Never mind, I see it goes with Python 3.11.7. I see that here  https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/allpkglists/2024.02-1/
